# MongoDB Closest Match on properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let says I have a Users collection in MongoDB whose schema looks like this:

```
{
    name: String,
    sport: String,
    favoriteColor: String
}
```

And lets say I passed in values like this to match a user on:

`{ name: "Thomas", sport: "Tennis", favoriteColor:"blue" }`

What I would like to do is match the user based off all those properties. However, if no user comes back, I would like to match a user on just these properties:

`{sport: "Tennis", favoriteColor:"blue" }`

And if no user comes back, I would like to match a user on just this property:

`{ favoriteColor: "blue" }`

Is it possible to do something like this in one query with Mongo? I saw the `$switch` condition in Mongo that will match on a case and then immediately return, but the problem is that I can't access the document it would have retrieved in the `then` block. It looks like you can only write strings in there.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Is the best thing (and only way) to just execute multiple `User.find({...})` queries?

Comment: There is no such functionality built in mongodb. Do you have a specific reason to perform such operation on server side ? You should use client side if else blocks to perform such requests. You can run all queries although not ideal in separate pipeline inside the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good case to use MongoDB text index:

First you need to create [text](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) index on those fields:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ name: "text", sport: "text", favoriteColor: "text" });
```

Then you can search the best match with "[$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)" limited by a number to show:

```
db.users.find( { $text: { $search: "Tennis blue Thomas" } } ).limit(10)
```

Comment: I think this is the most suitable case for you @Thomas (because you're performing a search query) especially that you could even [Control Search Results with Weights](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/) so you could consume your result by returned documents [scores](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/#proj._S_meta).

Comment: Hello how can I do this using regex? Like if I was searching for "Tennis" but I am writing letter by letter. I have tried db.users.find( {
    $text: {
        $search: {$regex:"ten"}
    } 
    } )

Comment: @tatuck, the text index is for semantic search, not lexical search. If you want to use lexical search with regex, create a normal index

Answer (score 3):

Try adding rank to all documents with weightage in aggregation pipeline, and sum the rank, `$sort` descending to get most matched documents on top

1. name -> 1
2. sport -> 2
3. favoriteColor -> 4

by doing this matching favoriteColor will always have higher weightage then sport and name or combination of both

aggregate pipeline

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match : {
        $or : [
            {"name" : {$eq :"Thomas"}},
            {"sport" : {$eq : "Tennis"}},
            {"favoriteColor" : {$eq : "blue"}}
        ]
    }},
    {$addFields : {
        rank : {$sum : [
            {$cond : [{$eq : ["$name", "Thomas"]}, 1, 0]},
            {$cond : [{$eq : ["$sport", "Tennis"]}, 2, 0]},
            {$cond : [{$eq : ["$favoriteColor", "blue"]}, 4, 0]}
        ]}
    }},
    {$match : {rank :{$gt : 0}}},
    {$sort : {rank : -1}}
])
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this query will satisfy your require condition, you can get relevant result in single db hit. Just create a query in `aggregate` pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match : {
        $or : [
            {"name" : {$eq :"Thomas"}},
            {"sport" : {$eq : "Tennis"}},
            {"favoriteColor" : {$eq : "blue"}}
        ]
}},
 {$addFields : {
        rank : {$sum : [
            {$cond : [{$and:[{$eq : ["$name", "Thomas"]},{$eq : ["$sport", "Tennis"]},{$eq : ["$favoriteColor", "blue"]}]  }  , 1, 0]},
            {$cond : [{$and:[{$eq : ["$name", "Thomas"]},{$eq : ["$sport", "Tennis"]}]  }  , 2, 0]},
            {$cond : [{$and:[{$eq : ["$name", "Thomas"]}]  } , 3, 0]},
        ]}
}},

{$group:{
    _id:null,
    doc:{$push:'$$ROOT'},
    rank:{$max:'$rank'}
}},
{$unwind:'$doc'},
{$redact: {
    $cond: {
      if: { $eq: [ "$doc.rank", '$rank' ] },
      then: "$$KEEP",
      else: "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  {
      $project:{
            name:'$doc.name',
            sport:'$doc.sport',
            favoriteColor:'$doc.favoriteColor',
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a query builder for `$match` pipe in mongoDB aggregate pipeline or use it for find also, create JavaScript object variable and build your query dynamically.

```
var query={};

if(name!=null){
        query['name']={ '$eq': name};
}
if(sport!=null){
            query['sport']={ '$eq': sport};
}
if(favoriteColor!=null){
            query['favoriteColor']={ '$eq': favoriteColor};
}

db.collection.find(query)
```

It will give exactly matched result on dynamic basis

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `$or`:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

I used it when I wanted to check if username or email exists..

Comment: Yeah but the problem is, it will always return the collection that meets the most basic `$or` condition, which would be `{ favoriteColor: blue }`

Comment: I guess I could do a complicated` $or` with an `$and` that would account for that

Comment: I thought it maybe query for first condition and then the second one, probably it's not the option.